# Error creating window handle Exception thrown on a single machine

Tags: memory

I was hoping someone can point me in the right direction regarding an issue I am having with the message "Error creating window handle". I know this usually points to a memory leak problem with the code, however this only happens on a single machine. If the code was the issue, I would be expecting it to happen on other machines as well.

I have other machines that this application runs on that do not run into this problem. I have tried reproducing in on my development machine and other machines in the office. Neither has been successful. I have tried watching the memory in Task Manager on the offending machine and it does not skyrocket up before it throws the error.

The offending machine is running Windows XP Professional SP3. Any ideas on how to proceed would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have just had the same problem in two different applications. For us, the problem was triggered by setting the Windows theme to "Windows Classic" rather than "Windows XP Style". The control that fails is a `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox` inside a [Developer Express XtraLayout](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Layout/) container, and our fix is to replace it with a `DevExpress.XtraEditors.ListBoxControl`.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. The offending machine has it's theme set to "Windows XP Style", so unfortunately, I don't think that is it. I will look at the controls on the offending form and remove them one by one and see if that helps me isolate which control is causing the issue.

Comment: @user961714 Good luck - these sort of individual machine problems are tough to track down.